# Save mp3 file into iphone music library

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mp3

I would like to interact with the mp3 player the iPhone: Is possible to save  a .mp3 file into  Iphone music library programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't planning on distributing this through Cydia then the answer is no this isn't possible. However, if you are going the jail break route check out [libiPodImport](https://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport) by H2CO3.